# Where is clone() overridden for arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, clone, overriding

An overridden `clone()` method of `java.lang.Object` class is available to all arrays.

Where is this method overridden for arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is defined by the [JLS 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The public method clone, which overrides the method of the same name in class Object and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type T[] is T[].
>   A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.

Where and how it is overriden is implementation specific. For HotSpot for example, you can find it [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp) at line 539 and following. If you drill down you will see that it calls a platform dependent method. For Windows-x86, for example, the `pd_conjoint_jlongs_atomic` method is located [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/os_cpu/windows_x86/vm/copy_windows_x86.inline.hpp) line 97 and uses assembly code.

Comment: " implementation specific." is that depends on the compiler

Comment: It is overridden in the definition of the array class. Nothing implementation-specific about that. Nowhere else it could possibly be. How that actually happens, or perhaps where that class is defined, might be implementation-specific, but it also doesn't matter, in any ascertainable way.

Comment: @EJP What I meant is that it is defined in the JVM and it could well be implemented differently between say HotSpot and a JVM that targets a specific environment.